# <mergeCell> dont exist after parsing, even though there are merge cells in xlsx file

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, saxparser

I'm using `apache.poi` to read .xlsx and .xlsm files in java.
I started stucking with the familiar problem `XSSFWorkbook wb = XSSFWorkbookFactory.createWorkbook(pkg)` which takes several minutes to load single simple file, I tried solutions in all forms...then I moved to use XSSFReader and SAX parser, and it seems to be exactly what I've looked for.
The Problem poped up again when I relized I need to get value from merged cells.

I saw [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11608605/how-to-get-merged-regions-using-apache-pois-event-api) how to get the list of merge cells from the file, its seems to work fine with new files that I create, but when I parse the real file that was given to me- it doesn't have `<mergeCells>`/`<mergeCell>` at all!

I suspected that the file somehow doesn't have merge cells (even though it seems to have). I checked it with the traditional way (XSSFWorkbook- which takes tons of time) and `sheet.getMergedRegions()` returns ArrayList of 14 items.. i.e. it has merge cells...

What can I do? Whats the problem with my file? and how can I handle with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is indeed as sily as it sounds, but my problem was... that I used code that processed only the first sheet.. and the sheet that contained the merge cells was the third one in the workbook..

I leave the answer here for someone stuck with the same problem.